# ePub readers for Windows that support continous scrolling?

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, software

I need to find an ePub reader application for Windows that support continuous page scrolling.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which ePub readers are available for Windows?](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/which-epub-readers-are-available-for-windows)

Answer (score 5):

Try the calibre ebook viewer: open your book and enable "Switch to flow mode" (the button on the top right corner)

Comment: Calibre comes as an e-book manager/converter program, and it is not always very obvious that if you look in its _program files_ folder there is also an eBook Viewer application, which is what Pasteur is talking about, called **ebook-viewer.exe**. It's not a very intuitive program, so if you've used it before, but failed to spot the _Switch to flow mode_ button, you will be startled to learn here that the text _will_ flow if you use it right!

Comment: @Ed999 I disagree about it the Calibre book viewer being hard to find. Double clicking on the book in the list of books opens it in the book viewer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I'm glad to hear that in the latest version of Calibre it's easy to find the ebook viewer. I must remember to finally get around to upgrading my old version!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox) with the [EPUBReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/) extension.

With the extension installed, open Firefox, then Ctrl+O to open a file. Locate and select your epub file.

By default, EPUBReader shows the ebook paginated. To get continuous scrolling, go to Settings (bottom left of the screen) and select Reading Styles > Website.

(Note: EPUBReader does not open ebooks with DRM.)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to do some research on your own before you ask a question, so that you can be very specific.

Epub readers using e-ink do not scroll because the screen refresh is too slow, though there is research to improve that (see for example [Bookeen's work](https://gigaom.com/2011/10/24/next-e-reader-innovation-scrolling-e-ink-web-pages/))

Of course this does not have to apply to epub reader software that uses more traditional screen displays, though these applications sometimes suffer from the same limitation (no scrolling) as they imitate e-ink eReaders.

Still, you should expect many epub reader applications with scrolling on systems using traditional display screens,  whatever the operating system. That is indeed the case. If you ask your favorite browser with keywords such as *`epub reader windows scrolling`*, you should get many answers to your question, as I did.

However there is no point in reproducing here these answers which I did not test myself, and which may change with time. Each reader can get more up to date answers by doing it on his own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new updated Microsoft Edge now. Its Epub reader is pretty good.
It has the page theme settings and text size and continuous scrolling too.

Comment: Are you sure it has continuous scrolling? It doesn't seem to have that option for me.

Answer (score -1):

I tried that google search, and got this page!lol! Far down the page I see the manual for Icecream reader that may work. [Reading mode. Controls](https://icecreamapps.com/Manuals/Ebook-Reader/controls.html)

Comment: That page says nothing about continuous scroll just how to use keys and mouse to scroll.